# Several errors under TEXworks

Tags: xetex

... when I compile with XeLaTeX this preamble

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\usepackage[paperwidth=142mm, paperheight=210mm,top=25mm, bottom=20mm, left=17mm, right=22mm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\usepackage{charter} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}

text

\end{document}
```

I get this error

```
\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.cfg")
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Erroneous variable \c__fontspec_shape_n_n_tl used!
l.3806 \emfontdeclare{ \emshape, \eminnershape }
```

Comment: texworks is not related to this error, that is just the editor to used to type the input. your fontspec and expl3 packages are not matching so updating both should fix the error.

Comment: and don't do this with luatex! `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xltxtra}` you have tagged the question xetex, but have used `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` which only works with luatex

Comment: I was using XeLaTex initially, I will see if I can take them off

Comment: xltxtra just loads fontspec plus some packages that you don't really need, and it's better to use fointspec directly, using T1 encoding in xetex makes no sense really as it restricts you to just using the fonts you could have used in classic tex (and all non-english hyphenation will be wrong)

Comment: Ok deleted. I will try reinstalling on the laptop re this question. (update is not working)

Comment: Also removed `\usepackage{fourier-orns}`, the compilation is much faster now. (this is all stuff remaining from tests)

Comment: reinstalled and updated, but it's update that did the trick. Who posts the solution ..